# How would I normalize a float array to the range [0.0, 1.0] in parallel?

Tags: opencl

I want to design a kernel in which I can pass an array of `float`s and have them all come out with the maximum being `1.0` and the minimum being `0.0`. Theoretically, each element would be mapped to something like `(x-min)/(max-min)`. How can I parallelize this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to split the problem into 2 kernels:

1. Reduction kernel

   - Divide your array into chunks of `N * M` elements each, where `N` is the number of work-items per group, and `M` is the number of array elements processed by each work-item.
   - Each work-item computes the `min()` and `max()` of its `M` items.
   - Within the workgroup, perform a [parallel reduction](https://dournac.org/info/gpu_sum_reduction) of `min` and `max` across the `N` work-items, giving you the min/max for each chunk.
   - With those values obtained, one of the items in the group can [use atomics](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomicFunctions.html) to update global min/max values. Given that you are using floats, you will need to use the [well known workaround](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2016-02-09/atomic-operations-for-floats-in-opencl-improved/) for the lack of atomic min/max/CAS operations on floats.
2. Application

   - After your first kernel has completed, you know that the global min and max values must be correct. You can compute your scale factor and normalisation offset, and then kick off as many work items as your array has elements, to multiply/add each array element to adjust it.

Tweak your values for N and M to find an optimum for a given OpenCL implementation and hardware combination. (Note that `M = 1` may be the optimum, i.e. launching straight into the parallel reduction.)

Having to synchronise between the two kernels is not ideal but I don't really see a way around that. If you have multiple independent arrays to process, you can hide the synchronisation overhead by submitting them all in parallel.